# How to use custom classifiers in ada?

Tags: r, adaboost

I am using adaboost from package `ada` to fit a model. In my understanding of adaboost, it combines multiple classifiers to get a better result. But in the function `ada`, I cannot find a parameter for this purpose. So what classifiers is `ada` using? How can I pass my classifiers into `ada`? Thank you.